# Meteor - how to securely store and access settings.json variable on the client-side?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am trying to access a secretKey on the client side of Meteor. I know that using Meteor.settings (http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_settings) seems to be the best way to access secrets.

My settings.json looks something like this:

```
{
  "public": {
    "secretKey": "topsecret!"
  }
}
```

I need to access secretKey on client-side javascript. However, when I go to the browser and in the console I can simply type in `Meteor.settings.public.secretKey` and the key would be right there!

Is there a better way for me to store and access this secret key on the client-side?

Comment: You could encrypt the key. Is this unique to each client?

Comment: No, the key is not unique to each client

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access private stuff from within the client, you must perform some basic permission handling with user accounts.

```
Meteor.methods({
  getSecretKey: function(){
    var user = Meteor.users.findOne(this.userId);
    if(!user){
      throw new Meteor.Error("login-error", "You must be logged in.");
    }
    if(!Roles.userIsInRole(user, "admin")){
      throw new Meteor.Error("admin-error", "You must be an admin.");
    }
    return Meteor.settings.secretKey;
  }
});
```

This pseudo-code is using a method to retrieve the secret key from the client and [`alanning:roles`](https://github.com/alanning/meteor-roles) to perform a simple user role check.

Comment: This makes sense, I'm assuming that this method is living on the server side right? It would be a security concern if someone is sniffing the network traffic and see the key getting passed?

Comment: Yes, that would be a server-only method because `Meteor.settings.secretKey` is not defined on the client anyway. As far as security is concerned this is the same in every webapp, using Meteor or not : get yourself a SSL certificate and use HTTPS.